# A 5 letter English word

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> A 5 letter English word.
>
> Remove the first letter, and you will get the name of a country.
>
> The last 3 letters give the opposite meaning of the word.
>
> What is the 5 letter word?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The answer is:

> woman

Remove first and you get country name

> Oman

Last three letters are

> man (opposite of woman)

Answer (score 3):

> No-man

The other answer certainly fits in better, but I think this works too.

Comment: My first thought. +1

Answer (score 0):

Might also

> NOMAN

First letter removed then

> OMAN

Opposite of

> NOMAN is MAN

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!! Please don't copy answers and do try to keep it as original as possible

Comment: I am sorry. I am new to this group and I was not aware that clicking on spoiler will reveal the answer. So I posted the answer without viewing the others answers. In case you have any questions, you may check my answer edits in which I tried to delete (but no such option found) and also tried to implement spoiler. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.